# Is there a way to add text at cursor position in emojionarea library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

Here is the current code snippet that is adding the text in the end but I want it at the cursor position.

```
<a href="#" class="aClass" data-text="Thank You">Test 1</a>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#emojionearea1").emojioneArea({
        pickerPosition: "right",
    });
});

$('.aClass').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); 
   var val = $('#emojionearea1').data("emojioneArea").getText(); //get prvious value
    $('#emojionearea1').data("emojioneArea").setText(val + "\r\n"+ 'Thank You');
  
});
```